# I have an error in my livestream php script

Tags: php, arrays

I have this error for livestream script

> ErrorException in 7b9ddd4cbecf92ef404b121398b5929782474a04.php line
>   11: Undefined offset: 0 (View:
>   /hermes/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04ap/b85/nf.hotelstravellecom1/public_html/w3schools/project/resources/views/admin/index.blade.php)
>   in 7b9ddd4cbecf92ef404b121398b5929782474a04.php line 11 at
>   CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), 1) in
>   PhpEngine.php line 44 at
>   PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/hermes/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04ap/b85/nf.hotelstravellecom1/public_html/w3schools/project/storage/framework/views/7b9ddd4cbecf92ef404b121398b5929782474a04.php',
>   array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application),
>   'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'settings' => array(),
>   'pagesettings' => array(), 'sociallinks' => array(), 'categories' =>
>   array(), 'code' => array(), 'ads728x90' => null, 'ads300x250' => null,
>   'ads300x600' => null)) in CompilerEngine.php line 59 at
>   CompilerEngine->get('/hermes/bosnacweb04/bosnacweb04ap/b85/nf.hotelstravellecom1/public_html/w3schools/project/resources/views/admin/index.blade.php',
>   array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application),
>   'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'settings' => array(),
>   'pagesettings' => array(), 'sociallinks' => array(), 'categories' =>
>   array(), 'code' => array(), 'ads728x90' => null, 'ads300x250' => null,
>   'ads300x600' => null)) in View.php line 137

Comment: Please include the part of the script that causes the error in your question

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you try to get element 0 from empty array in file:

> views/admin/index.blade.php line:11

Please add check block to your code, it can be something like this:

```
if (!empty($myArrayVariable)) {
    //do block on line 11))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help .i did that but the problem still exist

Comment: @MohamedGomaa please provide file `index.blade.php` in your post

Comment: Thank you sir ....site opened now fine ...but when i opened my admin panel this message appear and cannot log in although i updated the admin name and password message is (if (!empty($myArrayVariable)) { //do block on line 11)) }
)

Comment: In any case, please provide the template. I just wrote the php code, but you need to put blade code, so it is better to look the code, near line 11

Comment: Below line 11 , 12  , 13 ( <title>{{$settings[0]->title}} - Admin Panel</title>
 if (!empty($myArrayVariable)) {
    //do block on line 11))